# Visual Studio 2008 Debugger really slow with SSD

Tags: windows-7, ssd, performance, visual-studio, debug

My setup is a laptop with Windows 7 64-bit, Visual Studio 2008 SP1 on an Intel [X25-M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_solid-state_drives) 4 GB SSD with page file turned off (no need) and 2.2 GHz [Core Duo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_2_Duo).

What happens is weird:
When I build my project and attach the debugger the symbols load **REALLY** slowly... like 1 every 5 seconds.

Sometimes the symbols will fail to load at all. This is driving me crazy as this was a freshly installed Windows 7 box with default Visual Studio installation, working on [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) web applications...

I've never had to use symbol servers or any of that jazz so I'm quite frustrated. With this SSD it should breath fire as it does with loading and doing everything else.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Turn ON page file & see if that helps!

Comment: There is almost never a good reason to disable your pagefile.  See http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2008/11/17/3155406.aspx and http://lifehacker.com/5426041/understanding-the-windows-pagefile-and-why-you-shouldnt-disable-it

Answer (score 2):

Except for the fact that with a MLC based SSD write magnification from constant writing to disk is actually a slow operation. Add 4gb of RAM (so nothing ever gets paged) and you run out of a need to have a page file.

the machine runs awesomely doing everything BUT debugging. FYI this ended up being an issue with debugging with the T-SQL turned on. by unchecking this as an option it all came good.

But thanks for the shutdown without any research.